# Do pressure gradients affect diffusion speed for gases dissolved in liquids (scuba offgassing question)

Tags: pressure, gas, diffusion

This question comes from a scuba forum where we are discussing the technical scuba technique of breathing 100% O2 during stops at shallow depths to speed up the offgassing of nitrogen (N2) from body tissues.  What we are trying to determine is whether it makes a difference as far as N2 offgassing speed whether the stop takes places at 3m (1.3 atmospheres) or 6m (1.6atm).  These stops are during the ascent at the end of the dive.

From what I understand, this is essentially a question of diffusion of dissolved gases between two liquids surrounded by a permeable membrane where one liquid (body tissues other than blood) contains a given partial pressure of dissolved N2 and the other liquid (blood) contains only dissolved O2 (0% N2) at a partial pressure of either 1.3atm or 1.6atm.  Will the N2 diffuse (or otherwise move) more quickly into the liquid at 1.3atm or 1.6atm or does it not make any difference?

FWIW, there are two camps in this debate.  Camp 1 says the only thing that matters is the difference in partial pressures of N2 between the two tissues/liquids and since the ppN2 in the second liquid is 0 in both cases, then the diffusion rate will be identical.  Camp 2 says the increased pressure gradient between the N2 tissue and the 1.3atm liquid will drive a faster rate than the 1.6atm alternative. So far no one is saying that the deeper stop will result in faster offgassing.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Note that the concentration difference provides only the driving force. The flux, or rate at which the process occurs, depends also on the *mobility* of the nitrogen, which presumably carries  its own pressure dependence.

Comment: @Chemomechanics can you further expand on this?

Comment: The question currently focuses on concentration differences, but even at a set concentration difference, pressure can affect the driven movement of gas through a material in complex ways. A complete analysis of the problem would need to include this factor (termed the mobility) as well.